# What does CUPS's lp return?

Tags: ruby, shell, cups

I am writing a ruby script that prints by calling:

```
`/usr/bin/lp -d PrinterQueue -U #{user} #{fileToBePrinted}`
```

I would like to handle printing errors gracefully, but can't determine what `lp` returns when I execute it.  Usually it is a string like this:

> request id is PrinterQueue-68 (1 file(s))

Is there anywhere that describes what `lp` should return in strange cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the man page?

Comment: Doesn't discuss return values at all :(

Comment: `open3` might be a better call than backticks, that way you could grab the standard output, standard error, and the return value (which should be non-zero if there was an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to elaborate on my comment a little.

You should forget about using backticks for this and go straight to `Open3`. In particular, [`Open3.capture3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3):

```
out, err, status = Open3.capture3("/usr/bin/lp -d PrinterQueue -U #{user} #{fileToBePrinted}")
```

Then `out` will be a string containing the standard output from `lp`, `err` will be a string containing the standard error, and `status` will be a [`Process::Status`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html) instance. You check `status.success?` to see if the `lp` command worked and look at `err` (or show `err` to the user) if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The string `request id is PrinterQueue-68 (1 file(s))` is what the `lp` command *prints*, not what it *returns*.

If the `lp` command fails, it will return a non-zero exit status.  (It should also print an error message, but those messages aren't necessarily documented and might change from one version to the next.)

As I understand it, you can query the value of `$?` after invoking a command using backticks.  If the command succeeds, `$?` should be 0.  If it fails, it will have some non-zero value.

In a comment, @muistooshort suggests using `open3`; that's probably more robust and flexible than using backticks.